# Android Custom Search Suggestions: Query Two Parameters

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-searchmanager, search-suggestion

**SQLite Structure**

```
Table: Class

 Column1: classID (primary key)
 Column2: className


Table: Students

 Column1: studentID (primary key)
 Column2: classID (foreign key)
 Column3: studentName
```

**Question**

I have followed the [Adding Custom Suggestions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html) developer guide. The system correctly calls my content provider's query function when I type in the action bar search widget, and I can see search suggestions. My problem is that the query returns suggestions from the entire students table (which is the expected behaviour). But I need to limit the suggestions for a given classID. But the way the search suggestions work as described in the developer guide, only one parameter is passed to the query function, which in my case is selectionArgs[0].

**searchable.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:hint="@string/student_search_hint"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:searchSuggestThreshold="2"
    android:searchSuggestAuthority="com.androidapp.providers.database"
    android:searchSuggestSelection="studentName LIKE ? "
    android:searchSuggestIntentAction="android.intent.action.VIEW"
    android:searchMode="queryRewriteFromText" >
```

**excerpt from content provider**

```java
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,String[], selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

    ...

    queryBuilder.setTables(StudentsTable.TABLE);

    HashMap<String, String> columnMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    columnMap.put(BaseColumns._ID, StudentsTable.STUDENT_ID + " AS " + BaseColumns._ID);
    columnMap.put(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1, StudentsTable.NAME + " AS " + SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1);
    columnMap.put(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA, StudentsTable.STUDENT_ID + " AS " + SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA);
    queryBuilder.setProjectionMap(columnMap);

    limit = uri.getQueryParameter(SearchManager.SUGGEST_PARAMETER_LIMIT);
    selectionArgs[0] = "%"+selectionArgs[0] + "%";

    SQLiteDatabase db = database.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder, limit);

    return cursor;
}
```

If the query was initiated by me I could simply pass the second parameter (classID) in selectionArgs[1] and modify the selection string appropriately to form the correct SQLite statement.

But the query is initiated by the system. So how do I do this? Is there away to intercept the call to my content provider and modify the call to query?

Comment: jdirty hack but might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947016/pass-a-parameter-to-a-custom-search-suggestion-contentprovidor

Comment: @pskink Thank you. I was able to implement something that works for me following the link you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is helpful to someone, I spent days trying to figure this out, Thanks to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947016/pass-a-parameter-to-a-custom-search-suggestion-contentprovidor) provided by pskink I was able to implement the following solution:

**I created a variable in the content provider and an appropriate setter method:**

```java
public class MyContentProvider extends ContentProvider {

    ...

    private long id;

    ...

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;     
    }

}
```

**Then in my activity where I want to provide search suggestions for students in a particular class only, I do:**

```java
ContentProviderClient client = getContentResolver().acquireContentProviderClient("com.androidapp.providers.database");
MyContentProvider provider = (MyContentProvider)client.getLocalContentProvider();
provider.setId(rowid); //rowid is the classId from which students will be searched
client.release();
```

**Ammend the query function:**

```java
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,String[], selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

    ...

    queryBuilder.setTables(StudentsTable.TABLE);

    HashMap<String, String> columnMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    columnMap.put(BaseColumns._ID, StudentsTable.STUDENT_ID + " AS " + BaseColumns._ID);
    columnMap.put(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1, StudentsTable.NAME + " AS " + SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1);
    columnMap.put(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA, StudentsTable.STUDENT_ID + " AS " + SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA);
    queryBuilder.setProjectionMap(columnMap);

    limit = uri.getQueryParameter(SearchManager.SUGGEST_PARAMETER_LIMIT);
    selectionArgs[0] = "%" + selectionArgs[0] + "%";

    /*AMMENDMENT*/
    selection = selection + "AND " + StudentsTable.CLASS_ID + "=" + id;
    //This forms the SQL statement "WHERE studentName LIKE ? AND classId=3" (Assuming that rowid was 3).
    //As per normal Android behaviour the "?" mark will be replaced by selectionArgs[0].
    /*END*/

    SQLiteDatabase db = database.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder, limit);

    return cursor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just made a static variable for the second parameter on my content provider, and set it from the activity. I been thinking about it, and it's the cleanest workaround I have found!